# A letter or letters, which is right?

Tags: proximity-agreement

I helped students to write **a letter**

I helped students to write **letters**

I met people who had **a dream.**

I met people who had **dreams.**

Which is correct?
When the agent is plural,  the corresponding noun should be also plural?

Answer (score 1):

The first statement implies that you helped students to write the same letter.

It would apply, for example, if the students all had to seek permission from an authority to go on an organised outing.

It might also cover a situation when you helped each student to write a letter, but not necessarily the same letter.

That's to say; it's ambiguous. It can be understood in different ways.

The second statement means that you helped students to write letters in general. The might be several letters, different letters or any combination of letters.

Both statements are correct. They simply mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no rule requiring that the object be plural if the subject is plural**, even if there's a tendency towards a one-to-one relationship between that subject and that object, when using that verb. After all, usually a person writes a letter, so you might assume that several people would write several letters.

There's two reasons why there's no such requirement. One is that several people can collaborate on writing a single letter, and I've been involved in several documents that have been written by committees. Similarly, several people might *share* a dream - the idea of a shared dream is a pretty common thing, actually, but usually in the sense of a vision of the future, of how they want something to be.

Another is that saying "I helped students to write a letter" will also be used in situations where each of them writes a letter of their own - though usually it would mean that they were writing to a single brief. Write to your representative, for instance, or write a letter to the person you admire most. You can also use "helped students to write letters" for the same situation.

All of your sentences are correct, and there are some cases where two of them could be used for the same situation. They all parse differently, of course, and have in some sense a different meaning, but those meanings overlap in practice.